# Mongoose Return array from object value in array of object without JS workon

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to convert this array of object

```
 [{ category:"AAA" },{ category:"BBB" },{ category: "CCC" }]
```

Into this
 `["AAA","BBB","CCC"]` . I don't want to filter or use any array function in the backend but from the mongoDB itself.

Comment: Did you try something like this: Group.find({program: {$in: [...]}}).lean().select('category')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.distinct('category')`

should give you an array of unique values for that field.

Answer (score 0):

$map maps the object keys in the array to an array of the key values. Then use $addFields to transfrom the output

```
arr = [{ category:"AAA" },{ category:"BBB" },{ category: "CCC" }];
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "exclude": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$arr",
                    "as": "el",
                    "in": "$$el.category"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```